# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator' when adding numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing a function that converts list1 and list2 into arrays, and returning a numpy array of the sum of squares of elements of each list

```
list_1 = [1,2,3] 
list_2 = [1,2,3]

import numpy as np
def array_sum(list_1, list_2):

    assert len(list_1) == len(list_2), "both args must have the same number of elements"
   
    l1 = np.array(list_1)
    l2 = np.array(list_2)
    
    return (x**2 for x in l1) + (y**2 for y in l2)

array_sum(list_1,list_2)
```

I got this error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'

I later tried another way `return np.power(l1,2) + np.power(l2,2)` and it works, but I'm not sure where I went wrong in the original code for the return statement

Comment: `(x**2 for x in l1)` and `(y**2 for y in l2)` are generators and thus the error. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: In Python `[x for x in ...]` is a list comprehension, producing a list.  The same thing written with `()` is a `generator expression`, which sets up the same iteration, but does not actually run it.  `()` may also be used to group calculations, as in `(a+b)*c`.  Don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 1):

`(x**2 for x in l1)` is a generator and adding generators does not make any sense. Using lists (`[x ** 2 for x in l1] + [y ** 2 for y in l2]`) will make the error go away but will not give you the output you want since it will concatenate both lists.

Instead, you can simply take advantage of numpy vectorization, and just do

```
return l1 ** 2 + l2 ** 2
```

Which when incorporated into your code will return the array `[ 2  8 18]` (and is basically equivalent to your `np.power(l1, 2) + np.power(l2, 2)` attempt).

Answer (score -1):

Since you are converting to a NumPy array you can take advantage of NumPy broadcasting without using your loop. Which is more efficient.

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3]


def array_sum(list_1, list_2):
    assert len(list_1) == len(list_2), "both arguments must have the same number of elements"

    l1 = np.array(list_1)
    l2 = np.array(list_2)
    return (l1 **2, l2**2)
```